# Determining a set you get from change of variables $S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x > 0, y \geq 1, z \geq 1, xyz\leq1 \}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Let $S$ be $$\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:x > 0, y \geq 1, z \geq 1, xyz\leq1  \}$$

and the variable change given as:

$$x = u, y = \frac{u+v}{u}, z = \frac{u+v+w}{u+v}$$

Problem is determining the set you get from that variable change.

I'm really not sure how to plot this set by hand(and it's a problem from a test, so I should be able to, apparently), it doesn't even seem finite, so I assume it wouldn't make any sense to try to do this using the boundary of $S$.
Furthermore, I don't see how determining $u,v,w$ helps me at all. (Wolfram, for some reaosn, refuses to plot $xyz \leq 1$.)
Unless I made some calculation mistakes, it should be:
$$u=x, v = x(y-1), w = (z-1)xy$$

I'm really lost, cause I'm not sure what the exact approach here should be. Later on, I'm supposed to use this change of variables to compute $$\int_S 1$$ but I just don't see what I'm supposed to do with this.

Comment: Should that say $z = \frac{u+v+w}{u+v}$?

Comment: @B.Mehta true, will edit this now

Comment: Your set is "infinite" in the sense of having more than any finite number of points, but potentially it gives a finite volume when transformed in the way you describe.  It might help you to visualize the figure to fix a value for $x\gt 0$ and see what $y,z$ coordinates are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{gather}
x > 0,\  y \geq 1,\ z \geq 1,\ xyz \leq 1 \\\iff u>0,\ \frac{u+v}{u} \geq 1,\ \frac{u+v+w}{u+v} \geq 1,\ u \cdot \frac{u+v}{u}\cdot \frac{u+v+w}{u+v} \leq 1 \\
\iff u > 0,\ u+v \geq u,\ u+v+w\geq u+v,\ u+v+w \leq 1\\
\iff u>0,\ v \geq 0,\ w \geq0,\ u + v + w \leq 1
\end{gather}
Can you see how to sketch this set?

Comment: so this would be sufficient to do ? If so, then great! Now that I see it, it seems simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, notice that each line I wrote was an if and only if statement.